# How to integrate an Exp $\times$ Ga distribution

Tags: statistics, bayesian

My course notes (3rd-year module in Bayesian Statistics, unpublished) contain the following section.

> Assume we have data on the number of people queuing at an ATM at a specific hour for several
> randomly chosen days, and that we are interested in the mean time between two consecutive arrivals to the queue at some arbitrary point within this time.
>
> First, let $\textbf{x} = \{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ represent the observed data and assume these are a random sample from $\text{Po}(x_i\;|\;\lambda)$. We will use the conjugate prior $\text{Ga}(\lambda\;|\;a,b)$ to represent our prior knowledge, thus $$\pi(\lambda\;|\;\textbf{x})\propto\left[\lambda^se^{-n\lambda}\right]\times\left[\lambda^{a-1}e^{-b\lambda}\right]=\text{Ga}(\lambda\;|\;a^\ast,b^\ast),$$ where $a^\ast=a+s$ and $b^\ast=b+n$, with $s=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$ a sufficient statistic for $x_i$.
>
> Using standard queuing theory, the time within two consecutive arrivals, $y$, is distributed
> $\text{Ex}(y\;|\;\lambda)$. Thus, the predictive distribution is $$f(y\;|\;\textbf{x})=\int_0^\infty\lambda e^{-y\lambda}\frac{(b^\ast)^{a^\ast}}{\Gamma(a^\ast)}\lambda^{a^\ast-1}e^{-\lambda b^\ast}\;\text{d}\lambda=\frac{a^\ast}{b^\ast}\left(1+\frac{y}{b^\ast}\right)^{-(a^\ast+1)}.$$

Could someone help me understand how this integration is done?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Assuming that $b+y\neq 0$, let $\lambda=\frac t{b+y}$ and recognize a very well known function.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I had some trouble working it through, but as it happens I found a worked answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/646852/compound-of-gamma-and-exponential-distribution).